# How to stream video in gopro HERO4 with firmware 2.0.0

Tags: video-streaming, gopro

For older version of firmware working this solution:

Start streaming: http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&c1=start
and download streaming data using port UDP 8554.

Unfortunately this solution working only with old software version. With last one 02.00.00 not working. Gopro sending some data on UDP port but data is not correct and does not contain streaming informations (only about 1kB/sec). Also streaming method from HERO3 not working.

Answer (score 1):

These are the working commands for Hero4:

- Start Streaming: 
  http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&c1=start
- Restart Streaming:  http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&c1=restart
- Stop Streaming: http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&c1=stop

Video can be streamed by using aplay or ffplay on udp://:8554, connection must be kept alive using a script.

Comment: You may need to send a magic packet to hero4 first to start streaming.